# How i can add attachment to discord requests?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, discord

I'm trying to make python script that sending discord message + attachment but I don't know how to do it. Also i need to send the message from my discord account and not from a bot / webhook. This is my code so far:

```py
payload = {
    'content': "Hello" 
}

header = {
    'authorization': "token"
}

r = requests.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/874777490781003787/messages?limit=50", data=payload, headers=header)
```

Answer (score 3):

One-line solution with [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of requests library:

```py
with open('my_image.png', 'rb') as f: channel.send(file=discord.File(f))
```

If you really **must** use the requests library, you'll have to upload the file using `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` with the file properties being `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="your_attachment.png" Content-Type: image/png`, and the message properties being `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload_json" {"content":"your_content","tts":false}`.

So put them in a tuple nested in a dict like this:

```
files = {
    'file': ('./picture.jpg', open('./picture.jpg', 'rb')),
    
}

r = requests.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/874777490781003787/messages?limit=50", data=payload, headers=header, files=files)
```

Read the [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) here.